# Totem and MPlayer not displaying video correctly in Mint 11

Tags: video, linux-mint, mplayer, totem

Whenever I try to play a video file in Totem or MPlayer (I've tested OGV, MP4, MPG), it displays in very odd ways (depending on program). Videos play fine in VLC, Banshee, Google Chrome etc. I think I have all correct the codecs installed.. I have searched the webs far and wide without finding anything, so any help would be much appreciated.


**Totem**
Very dark blue and red (only blue in this image) (yes, that's Mary and Pippin)
[image: Totem]

**MPlayer**
Very pixelated/chunky. whenever I skip to different times, it will fully load for a frame then the top half will go chunky while the bottom half is fine. 
[image: MPlayer]

Comment: What about MPlayer's alternate video outputs?

Comment: Wow, that actually fixed it for MPlayer, using the gl output. Do you know what they default to, so I can try to fix that?

Comment: The default is almost surely XVideo.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to start it from a terminal, mplayer outputs a bunch of stats. Try different outputs from
`mplayer -vo help`